# setState isn't called while executing callback function

Tags: flutter, dart

This code snippet is called on initState().

```
  void _countDown() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    if (mounted) {
    setState(() {
      driverArrived = true;
    });
    widget.onDriverReached();
    }
 }
```

onDriverReached is a VoidCallback

```
class ClientDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback  onDriverReached;
  ClientDetail({this.onDriverReached});
  @override
  _ClientDetailState createState() => _ClientDetailState();
}
```

The callback function executes perfectly but setState is never called. If i remove the callback , setState is called and changes appear on the widget. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you try to call setState inside your callback?

Comment: how do i call setstate inside my callback ? globalState ?

Comment: I saw "onDriverReached" is a callback of ClientDetail class. So I mean why dont you can try to call the setState inside the VoidCallback function from another widget that initialize ClientDetail class?